# How to make a constant (surface) shader?

Tags: shaders

I'd like to create a constant shader (XSI) for an object in my scene (surface shader in Maya). If I plug a ramp with both colours of the ramp set to the same colour into the surface port of the material out put, I get what I need. However that material seems to be emissive. I don't want this object to affect the rest of the scene, just be a flat colour.
Is there a simple way to do this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want one color, don't use a *Color Ramp*, simply take a *Input* > *RGB* node. Yes, it is emissive if you directly plug it into the *Material Output*, because you have no surface shader inbetween that tells Blender the properties of the surface.

However, if you want it flat shaded without any reflections or shadows on it, then you can do it that way. If you then go to the *Object Properties* > *Visibility* > *Ray Visibility* and disable everything except for *Camera*, the object will have no effect on other objects in the scene. But this also means it will throw no shadows and not be visible in reflections. To still throw shadows, enable *Shadow* visibility again. To be visible in reflections, enable *Glossy* again - but this means the glossy surface will also receive light emission from the object which can be reflected on other objects in the scene.

[image: flat shaded inaffective object]

Comment: Perfect! Many thanks